# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:(…) directive_normalizer.js:92

Tags: angular, ionic2

In Ionic 2 (and guess it is true with regular Angular 2 as well), as I develop, I often run in that error: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:(…) directive_normalizer.js:92`.

At first I did not get it (also the word `Template` in the error message is quite relevant about where to search), but I've solved it and will leave my remarks here in case it can save time to people wondering about that issue.

**So I appologize in advance**: no code and I will answer my own question.

Comment: Answering your own question [is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), so no apology needed.

Comment: I ve been voted down for doing so once:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to a typo error in one of the html template file called.

On your pages, in the @Component you have something like:

```
@Component{
...  
templateUrl: "your-template-file.html",
...  
}
```

The error is raised because there is a typo error in one the files similar to "your-template-file.html": like one tag which has been forgotten to be closed, or another HTML inconsistent syntax.

Also, you might be closing the directive's tag incorrectly, e.g. `<my-tag/>` as opposed to `<my-tag></my-tag>`.